# Monodevelop on OS X and Displaying UTF-8

Tags: macos, utf-8, mono, monodevelop

Two Questions

1. **Does using Copy or paste cause monodevelop to crash, or is it just me?** If you have Monodevelop installed, please can you test this, I fount that both shortcuts and from the menus cause it to crash. I seem unable to find information about this on google, though would personally consider this quite a major bug.
2. **How can UTF-8 characters be displayed** in monodevelop and mono programs? Although they output fine in Terminal. It is similar to [Can't display multi byte string on MonoDevelop Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775061/cant-display-multi-byte-string-on-monodevelop-mac-os-x) , but none of the solutions seem relevant as 2.4 has now been released.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Several common Mac programs have clipboard manipulation features that seem to corrupt MD's memory. It's a known issue and is documented [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support#MonoDevelop_crashes_when_you_copy_text).
2. Unfortunately my answer remains that same [as my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775061/cant-display-multi-byte-string-on-monodevelop-mac-os-x/2805894#2805894) in the thread you linked: the Mac version of the Pango library that MonoDevelop uses for font rendering does not support glyph fallbacks, but you may be able to work around this by using a font that contains all the glyphs you need. If you could be more specific about the charsets and where you are seeing issues, we may be able to provide more specific answers.

[NOTE: both these issues have since been fixed]

Answer (score 2):

1) I think it's just you or the Mac version of MonoDevelop has some serious bugs. Here I'm running Linux and it works fine.

2) There seems to be some bugs with displaying UTF characters correctly on the Mac version.

From the link you posted someone suggested to do this: In MonoDevelop go to File->Save As-> Character Encoding: -> Unicode (UTF-16).

If the above doesn't work I recommend that you use the [VMware image](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) provided by the Mono Project with the latest Mono, MonoDevelop and other stuff which is running on openSUSE.
You can try to develop in the virtual machine and port it to Mac to see if the strings are displayed correctly.

C# has three main IDEs: **Microsoft Visual Studio**, **SharpDevelop**, and **MonoDevelop** [*].

Visual Studio and SharpDevelop are *Windows only* IDEs. MonoDevelop is the only one that's cross-platform. (Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, FreeBSD)

[*] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.23